# Do I need to provide getters/setters for Auditable fields in Spring Data?

Tags: java, spring-data, audit

I just finished reading the docs for [Spring Data Auditing](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/1.5.x/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.auditing) but I am unclear about something.  The docs indicate that just using the `@CreatedBy`, `@CreatedDate`, etc are enough to mark the fields as auditable fields.  However, it doesn't indicate anything about requiring getters or setters.

Does Spring Data use aspects to inject getters/setters, or must I do that manually?  To further confuse the issue, the docs indicate that I can extend the `Auditable` interface which exposes all the getters and setters if I do not want to use annotations.  Which, in my mind, implies that the getters & setters will be generated automatically if I use the annotations.

However, when I look at the compiled .class file with a decompiler, I do not see any getters & setters that have been injected.

With the annotations, is there some other mechanism to access these audit fields from within my code, or must I intentionally create setters/getters if that is functionality that I want?

Comment: Did you actually try it out?

Comment: @AdamArold - yes - I added a `@CreatedDate` field to my entity, and recompiled it.  I then looked at the generated .class file with my decompiler and didn't see any injected getter/setter for my audit field.  Hence the question.  If Spring does automatically inject the relevant getters/setters, it might imply that I am missing some aspect library in my maven configuration.

Comment: You should do some functional testing.

Comment: @AdamArold I presume your last comment means that it does decorate it somehow.  Do you know what mechanism Spring uses to decorate my classes?  Is it using some form of LTW?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#auditing.basics), you currently have two options: annotation based auditing and interface based auditing:

For interface based auditing your object implements `Auditable` and our infrastructure will call the setters exposed through the interface (see the [relevant snippet of AuditableBeanWrapperFactory](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/51b128fac1c17c8327d6fdd8c7ef87b039ac6c60/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/auditing/AuditableBeanWrapperFactory.java#L50)).

For annotation based auditing we currently only support setting the auditing information directly into the field (see [ReflectionAuditingBeanWrapper](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/51b128fac1c17c8327d6fdd8c7ef87b039ac6c60/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/auditing/AuditableBeanWrapperFactory.java#L120) for details). There's a [ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-365) in our tracker to make the annotation based solution accessor aware as well and we will have this fixed in the first milestone of upcoming release train [Dijkstra](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Dijkstra).